# Can't import python module using a conda environment in Snakemake rule

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, snakemake

I created a Conda environment with python 3.5, in order to run Snakemake workflows. I'm using separate Conda environments in Snakemake rules. I would like to run one of them using python2 libs, however here I can't seem to import a specific module.

This is my rule's environment:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - zeep
```

My rule is calling a python script using python2:

```
python2 my_script.py
```

And the python script contains this import:

```
from zeep import Client
```

When I run the workflow I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named zeep
```

Could this be an issue related to python versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not specifying the Python version in the rules environment, I assume it is selecting Python 3.5 as the default. If you modify your environment like this:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=2.7.13
  - zeep
```

the environment will use Python 2.7.13 instead, and the script will work.

Comment: Thanks! I just got my hands on Conda, I did not think of that. Works just fine now.

Comment: how to handle versions of python in the envs variable ? certain dependencies may require python 3 and some python 2. ?